# UWP: Passing value from UserControl to MainPage

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp

I have created a UserControl where everything is done in the UserControl.xaml.cs and I want a specific property (called "Value") from the UserControl to be passed to a TextBlock which is created in the MainPage. To test the access of the property, I have created a TextBlock within the UserControl and Bind to Text to "Value" via `Text={Binding Path=Value}` and it works fine. How do I have to bind the TextBlock from the MainPage to achieve the same?

Comment: Do you want to Bind the `Value` property in `UserControl` to a `TextBlock` in MainPage? If Yes then use `Text={x:Bind UserControl.Value}`

Comment: seems like this is the way to go, but it seems like I'm missing data context somewhere since I get this error `Cannot resolve field or property 'UserControl' in data context of type 'MyProject.TestApplication.MainPage'

Comment: Did you create `Value` as a DependencyProperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the `ElementName` part of the Binding to access the Value from the UserControl. To do this you'll have to give your UserControl an `x:Name` then set up your Binding like so:

```
Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=MyUserControl}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created your Property as a DependencyProperty. You can do it using below code

```
public string Value
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl ), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

You can get the value in XAML using below code

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=Value}"/>
```

(OR)

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CustomInkControl.Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**Note:** Use `x:Bind` because It is efficient than `Binding`

Comment: yes, while i alredy had my Property as a DependencyProperty, i was missing the ElementName. So thank you and @jsmyth886!

Comment: @Nigel-Lee You could also use `x:Bind` and set `Mode=OneWay`. I have updated the answer.